# Named capture in Ruby's regular expressions

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to extract information from a line of text with relatively long regular expression. Below is a simplified regexp that describes the problem.

```
line = "Internet  10.9.68.178           127   c07b.bce9.7d41  ARPA   Vlan2"
```

If I try to match this line directly without trying to 'save' regexp into a variable, it works very  well:

```
[223] pry(main)> /Internet\s+(?<ipaddr>\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})/  =~ line
=> 0
[224] pry(main)> ipaddr
=> "10.9.68.178"
[225] pry(main)> $1
=> "10.9.68.178"
```

Now, when I try to do exact same thing with 'stored' version of the regexp, it fails miserably:

```
  [226] pry(main)> ipaddr = nil   # ensure that it's cleared before match

  [227] pry(main)> myreg = /Internet\s+(?<ipaddr>\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})/
  => /Internet\s+(?<ipaddr>\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})/
  [228] pry(main)> myreg =~ line
  => 0
  [229] pry(main)> ipaddr
  => nil
  [230] pry(main)> $1
  => "10.9.68.178"
```

I have also tried to call `match` method directly and it seems to work:

```
[231] pry(main)> myreg.match(line)
=> #<MatchData "Internet  10.9.68.178" ipaddr:"10.9.68.178">
```

but this means for a simple `if` statement I need to do something like this:

```
if m = myreg.match(line)
   do_stuff m[:ipaddr]
end
```

instead of simply

```
if myreg =~ line
   do_stuff ipaddr
end
```

Any ideas as to why the names are not captured correctly in this instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting. I've looked this up in the [Ruby Documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Regexp.html#method-i-3D-7E).

It says there:

> The assignment does not occur if the regexp is not a literal.

That's why `/Internet\s+(?<ipaddr>\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})/  =~ line` works, but `myreg =~ line` does not.

Thanks for making me learn something new. :)

Comment: thanks, I've skimmed through that page multiple times and somehow still missed it...